# Custom Permissions in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, permissions

I have this get View that I want to check IsOwner Permission.

Permission Class

```
class IsOwnerVendor(permissions.BasePermission):

def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
    print(f"Vendor Email:{obj.vendor_id.email}")
    print(f"Loggon user:{obj.vendor_id.email}" )
    return obj.vendor_id.email == request.user
```

this is my object Model

```
class Menu(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    price = models.FloatField()
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    menu_cat = models.CharField(choices=MENU_CAT, max_length=5)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_edited = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    vendor_id = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_recurring = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    recurring_freq = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

Vendor Model

```
class Vendor(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    business_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()
    phone_number = PhoneField(help_text='Vendor phone number')
    registered_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.business_name
```

and this is my view

```
class MenuDetailView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsOwnerVendor | IsOwnerVendor]

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == 'PUT':
            return MenuUpdateSerializer
        elif self.request.method == 'GET':
            return MenuListSerializer
        else:
            return MenuListSerializer

    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            obj = Menu.objects.get(pk=pk, )
            self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
            return obj
        except Menu.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    @method_permission_classes((IsOwnerVendor,))
    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        my_menu = self.get_object(pk=pk)
        menu_serializer = MenuListSerializer(my_menu)
        return Response(menu_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

When I try to access the view, I always get the error below

```
{
    "detail": "You do not have permission to perform this action."
}
```

I have read the DRF doc and I still cannot pinpoint where my issue lies.

I also printed the Permission checkers on the console and saw that it was supposed to return true.
[image]

Comment: please post model Vendor detail.

Comment: try `return obj.vendor_id.email == request.user.email` ?

Comment: @Ykh, I have edited to add the Vendor model. and I have also tired your method. I still get same result.

Comment: try `return obj.vendor_id.user == request.user`

Comment: @Ykh, I just retried using return obj.vendor_id.email == request.user.email and now it's working. I would have placed a bet that I tried it. I have spent a couple of hours trying to pinpoint the exact problem. Thanks buddy. RESPECT. Can you reply as an answer so I Accept it?

Comment: the problem is has_object_permission return False, you can print log or set breakpoint to see why this method return False.

Comment: @Ykh, It has been resolved. Using your first approach. I would've swore I tried it before. Please reply as an answer so I can mark it accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main point is you should let has_object_permission method return True, you can try:

`return obj.vendor_id.email == request.user.email` or
`return obj.vendor_id.user == request.user`, if this still not work, you can print log or set breakpoint to see why this method return False.Remember to restart you localserver before you next test.